# Scala Swing Origin of the Title Field

Tags: swing, scala, user-interface

Good evening ,

I have a very simple question regarding the scala.swing module !

When I initialize a new MainFrame Object like:

```
 ... new MainFrame { ... }
```

Then of course  I can give the window a title and location etc... :

```
new MainFrame {
    title = "BlaBlaBla"
    location = new Point(200 , 300)
```

My Question is from which class were the fields title and location

inherited, cause I can't find them in swing.MainFrame   !?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` is a field of the trait `RichWindow`; `position` is a field of `UIElement`, the base trait of all user interface elements (including `RichWindow`).

`MainFrame` extends the class `Frame`, which implements the trait `RichWindow`.

Here's an except of the actual code :

```
sealed trait RichWindow extends Window {
  ...
  def title: String = peer.getTitle
}
```

Scala swing rewrote the component hierarchy of java swing, and makes heavy use of multiple inheritance, a feature notoriously lacking in java. So in general, you should look for **traits**, not classes :)